# normal Activity switching to TabActivity

Tags: android

I have 2 activity: A, B. The first is an normal Activity and the second an TabActivity. Inside A i have a clickable button that make an intent to call the TabActivity the output showing black screen..how to show the UI of both the screens?tell me the solution?i need code please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

or use this tutorial:

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/03/tutorial-how-to-start-a-new-activity/

Comment: i am asking about switching from normal activity to TabActivity..I.e.one screen to another Screen containing TabActivity..The ui elements are disappearing..how to display the ui elements